# NullPointerException Android Drawing app in onDraw() method?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, ondraw

I'm trying to load a picture to paint on top of in an Android app but can't seem to load the to paint on top of.

The ErrorLog for activity_main.xml tells me I have a problem in my onDraw() method in my custom views class at the line canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,mBitmapPaint);`

---

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2.DrawingView

        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/crayon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

My MainActivity.java file:

```
package edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.crayon);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas (mBitmap);


    //DrawingView drawingView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

My Custom View class:

```
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;

private Canvas mCanvas;
private Canvas shadowCanvas;

private Bitmap colorBitmap;
private Bitmap grayscaleBitmap;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Bitmap shadowBitmap;

private Paint mBitmapPaint;

private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    mPath = new Path();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    mCanvas = new Canvas ();

    paths.add(mPath);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,mBitmapPaint);

    for (Path p : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    }
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
}


public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: bcoz your mBitmap is null. iitialize it either inside onSizeChanged or class constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one variable `mBitmap` which is not initialized, That's why it is throwing NPE.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,mBitmapPaint);             // NPE here 

    for (Path p : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);                     
    }
}
```

You need to initialized this variable.

Comment: I'm still getting a NullPointerException at `mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,mBitmapPaint);`?

Comment: where you have initialize `mBitmap` ??

Comment: I wonder how changing `canvas` to `mCanvas` will solve Exception? `canvas` will never be `null` passed through `onDraw()` method

Comment: Oh I guess I never initliazed `mBitmap`. Should I initialize it in onDraw since if I try to initialize it in constructor for DrawingView it tells me "the constructor Bitmap() is not visible"

Comment: @Opal you shouldn't initialize it onDraw() method instead you can do it in contructor.

Comment: @user3301551 any idea on how to make the constructor Bitmap visible? Also, it's not "visible" in onDraw() so that was wrong on my part

Comment: @Opal, I mean you can declare it in `public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

Comment: @Opal which `Bitmap` you want to draw on `Canvas`? is that from `drawable` resources?

Comment: @GopalRao yes that's correct! I have a picture called crayon.png located in `res/drawable`

Comment: @user3301551 even if I declare it in that as `private Bitmap mBitmap = new Bitmap();` I still get the same error

Comment: in which line you are writting this `private Bitmap mBitmap = new Bitmap();`

Comment: @user3301551 after `super(context, attrs);`

Comment: @Opal initialize `mBitmap` in constructor as `mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.crayon)`...

Comment: @Opal yes you did, but both are two different classes.

Comment: @Opal how do you think initializing `Bitmap` in `Activity` will initialize the `Bitmap` in `DrawView`? instead of initializing in `Activity`'s `onCreate()`, initialize it in `DrawView` constructor or else pass the initialized `Bitmap` to `DrawView` through setter method...